# How do I change my TGV reservation to allow for print-at-home option?

Tags: trains, france, tickets

I booked my TGV ticket on the French version of voyages-sncf.com. Not being able to read French, I wasn't aware at the time that there was a print-at-home option. Just in case my train arrives late, I would want a printed ticket instead of collecting it at the ticket window. On the e-mail it says I've chosen the kiosk option, but is there any way to change it so that I can print it out?

Note: I have contacted voyages-sncf, but it was e-mail only, so I don't know when I'll get a response.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, because print-at-home tickets are nominative whereas collect-at-station tickets are not (you need to have the credit card used to buy the ticket when you collect it, but you can then give it to someone else). If it's possible, you should be able to do it from “[suivi de commandes](http://www.voyages-sncf.com/services-train/suivi-commande)”. If you need help with the French, drop down to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) and ping me (offer valid until I go to bed tonight).

Comment: I has been a while since I went to collect a ticket at the station, but I thought that you can also collect your tickets at automatic vending machines. You need to give your reservation code and the original credit card, but again the last time I collected a ticket this way was in 2004

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the offer. I saw the message too late.

Comment: @Frietjeoorlog Collecting a ticket at a ticket machine only works with French credit cards. If you have a foreign credit card, you have to go to a ticket window.

Comment: @gilles That makes sense, I had a "carte blue" (local Visa+ card) in 2004

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to change your ticket delivery type after booking. Your only option would be to obtain a refund (if your fare conditions allow it) and then book a new ticket.

I'm not sure how good the customer service at voyages-sncf is, but for future reference you can book almost all the same tickets at my website [loco2.com](http://loco2.com) and we have excellent customer service for dealing with this kind of issue as [demonstrated by our excellent ratings on Trustpilot](http://www.trustpilot.co.uk/review/loco2.com).

Comment: How can you compare customer service if you don't know customer service of sncf?

Comment: I can now confirm that it's not possible. Customer service responded.

Comment: @Frietjeoorlog I have not compared customer service, I just explained that Loco2's customer service is excellent

Comment: @Jamie it is quite pretentious to say you are excellent. You are saying it is YOUR website.

Comment: @Frietjeoorlog I am sorry that you see me as pretentious. I was referring to the "Excellent" rating that we have from 219 reviews on the independent review site, Trustpilot http://www.trustpilot.co.uk/review/loco2.com. We set up Loco2 because we had been frustrated with the customer service and user experience when booking train tickets ourselves, so we strive to be better